# How to add multiple object in ArrayList which declared generic?

Tags: java

How to do that?

Following is tried code.

[Tried code]

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String, Integer, Date> myArray = new ArrayList<String, Integer, Date>();

        myArray.add("FIRST");
        myArray.add("SECOND");
        myArray.add("THIRD");

        // add multiple object
        myArray.add(new Integer(10));

        // add multiple object
        myArray.add(new Date());

    }
}
```

Comment: What you are going to achieve by this? Seems you are doing something wrong

Comment: I'd like to limit adding objects by specifying objects.

Comment: For example as above, String, Interger, date.

Comment: You can't do like that, I mean, you can't make it add only those three object types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below line wouldn't even compile.

```
ArrayList<String, Integer, Date> myArray = new ArrayList<String, Integer, Date>();
```

What you're trying to achieve can be done using

```
ArrayList<Object> myArray = new ArrayList<>(); // Object type
```

but it is not at all a recommended option to do it. And while fetching the values back from the ArrayList, you need to handle the different types of objects manually, which is quite troublesome as well.

Therefore, it is always create `ArrayList` of the specific types you want to use.

```
ArrayList<String> myString = new ArrayList<>(); // For strings
ArrayList<Date> myDates = new ArrayList<>(); // For Date
```

Comment: I can't understand why generic of JAVA doesn't have this feature which can specify each objects.

Comment: Thank R.J. You make me know it's recommended way.

Comment: @user868754 - Glad to be of help to you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, But not recommended.

```
ArrayList<Object> myArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Taking `Object` as a type , it accept all the types.

```
ArrayList<Object> myArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
myArray.add("FIRST");   //accepted
myArray.add(new Integer(10));  //accepted
myArray.add(new Date());  //accepted
```

So while getting also you need to take care of which `Object` you are getting back.

But, good recommendation is to take that individual list's for each type.